# Can I stay at someone other than my Schengen sponsor?

Tags: visas, germany, pakistani-citizens

I am writing this query from Pakistan. I will be applying for a short term visitor visa for Germany next week. I intend to visit both my parents who reside there. My father has German citizenship but is unable to sponsor me on account of him being retired and living on pension from the state. I have received an invitation letter from a sponsor, who happens to be a family friend.

I will be covering my own expenses during the stay and have corresponding documents to show that.

Can I stay with my parents during the visit, even if someone else has extended an invitation letter to me? Should I mention it in the covering letter for the sponsor letter?

Comment: Yes, you can indicate that your parents will house you and therefore cover the housing cost.

Comment: If you are covering your own costs, and staying with your father, a German citizen, why do you need a sponsor?

Comment: Sponsor letter from a resident in Germany is one of the visa requirements.   Probably a guarantor for my return at the end of the trip.

Comment: Noone is going to check where you're going exactly. You shouldn't lie, but you don't have to include your entire itinerary.

Answer (score 1):

As you are self-paying for the trip to Germany, and have provided proof of your financial status, you can stay with your relatives and should only need the invitation letter from them. If you have also had to include a Verpflichtungserklärung, the affidavit/declaration of support, it imposes a number of legal financial obligations on the person who obtained it on your behalf, but does not mean that you must stay with them.